# Create a new column based on formula involving other column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

First, I want to create a new column called "total price" based on the type of product defined by column "type"(1 : 5). Data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame('type'=c(1,2,3,4,5), 'quantity'=c(1,20,3,4,50))
df
  type quantity
1   1    1         
2   2   20
3   3    3
4   4    4
5   5   50
```

Total price can be calculated by multiplying the quantity of each product by the corresponding price:

***The price for each type of product:  Type 1 - $10; Type 2- $20;Type 3- $30;Type 4- $40;Type 5- $50

So that I would expect something looks like this:

```
       type quantity totalprice
    1   1    1           10
    2   2   20          400
    3   3    3           90
    4   4    4          160
    5   5   50         2500
```

Then, I need to join this newly created column with the original data as the last column.

I guess the pseudo code looks something like this:

```
Part 1)
if df$type == "1" , totalprice = df$quantity * 10,
if df$type == "2", totalprice = df$quantity * 20,
if df$type == "3", totalprice = df$quantity * 30,
if df$type == "4", totalprice = df$quantity * 40

Part2)
Collect these values in a column called totalprice and join it to df.
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Could you give expected outcome table? and what is the corresponding price??

Comment: Hi Juhyeon, I've updated the expected outcome table(the last column). Thanks

Comment: You need to add a second data frame with `df2$type` and `df2$multiplyer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Elin, create a reference dataframe with all the types and their corresponding `price`. `merge` it with your original `df` by `"type"` and then multiply `quantity * price`

```
ref_data <- data.frame(type = 1:5, price = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
transform(merge(df, ref_data, by = "type"), totalprice = quantity * price)

#  type quantity price totalprice
#1    1        1    10         10
#2    2       20    20        400
#3    3        3    30         90
#4    4        4    40        160
#5    5       50    50       2500
```

In `dplyr`, you could do

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df, ref_data, by = "type") %>%
    mutate(totalprice = quantity * price)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just adding a multiplier column corresponding to the `type`, and then using that to generate the total price:

```
df$multiplier <- 10
df$totalprice <- df$multiplier * df$quantity
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer. The challenge is that the price should be conditional on the type of product, before multiplying by the quantity. Is there a good way to do that?  Thanks

Comment: Your multiplier simply appears to be a fixed value of 10, for all types.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Tim, the price is different for each type of product: Type 1 - 10; Type 2- 20;Type 3- 30;Type 4- 40;Type 5- 50

Comment: Your expected results are always type*quantity*10 ... please provide a more complete example that shows that this is not true (or don't make the multiplier match the type).

Answer (score 1):

If the corresponding price have a strict rule (type X 10), it can be generated by this code:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(price = type * 10,
         totalprice = quantity * price)
```

Do you have more rows at the df? or is there no rule for the price?

Comment: Hi Juhyeon, thanks for your answer. Is there a way to take into account different conditions(types of product) at the same time since the price for different product is different?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I cannot understand fully your idea. Could you give some example?

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not clear. What I meant was that the price for each type of product is different: Type 1 - $10; Type 2- $20;Type 3- $30;Type 4- $40;Type 5- $50. For example, if the type of product is 1, price for 1 unit is $10, total price for 1 is $10; if the type of product is 2, price for 1 unit is $20, total price for 20 of them is $400;  if the type of product is 3, price for 1 unit is $30, total price for 3 of them is $90... I hope this is more clear